# How to set the initial state in React based on a Rx.ReplaySubject model

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to make react both isomporpic and Rx.js driven.

My use case (at this point) is getting the locale into state of my components so that my i18n can use it for string selection.

Presuming I have a simple model for locale

```
import Rx from 'rxjs';

const localeModel = new Rx.ReplaySubject('en');

export default localeModel;
```

how can I set the initial state of the compoent

```
class MyHeader extends Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {locale: //???? 
         };
    }
}
```

I can of course use componentDidMount, subscribe, and setState to *eventually* get the right locale, but I want to have it have the right value on the server.

(in reality I want to do a lot more than just set the locale - I want to pull strings into my page based on the known ID of the component and the locale).

So, given that Rx.js's basic philosophy is streaming, how do I get the current value of the observable synchronously in the constructor and stay in the canon of using Rx in a streaming context?

Comment: do you have localModel.js file right ?

Comment: yes, in the real implementation. I munged it all together to simplify the question

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `import` like

```
import i18n from 'localModel'

class MyHeader extends Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {locale: i18n}
         };
    }
}
```